# Why python handles varible strangely?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Interestingly enough, when I change the variable type first it resulted in a error of unsupported oprand type of adding **str** and **int**:

```
average = ['12','23','34','45','56','67','78','89','90','100']
avenum = 0

for each in average:
    int(each)
    avenum = avenum + each
```

However in this configuration the code will execute:

```
average = ['12','23','34','45','56','67','78','89','90','100']
avenum = 0
for each in average:
    avenum = avenum + int(each)
```

I am curious to know the difference between those two and why python ahandle them differently.

Comment: You need to store the change in a variable. Ex: `each = int(each)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is the name of a *class*:

```
>>> each = 42
>>> isinstance(each, int)
True
```

In python we create an object of a given class using the general syntax:

```
object-name = class-name(constructor-parameters)
```

So when you do:

```
int(each)
```

you are creating a new `int` object but then not assigning a name to it.

```
each = int(each)
```

will call the `int` constructor using the `str` object referred to by `each`.  This will return a new `int` object and the name `each` now refers to that object.  The original `str` object has its reference count decremented and, if zero, becomes a candidate for destruction.

No `str` or `int` methods or functions change those objects, they return a new one, since those objects are read-only, or *immutable*.

That's the theory anyway.  Implementations of python might optimise `int` and `str` because they are such common objects, but that's a detail that should be invisible to the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

`int(each)` will not change the value or type of `each`, the return value of `int(each)` is dropped. So the line `int(each)` in the first code have no use to the later execution.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, we see `int()` does **not** modify the item passed to it (like, for instance, `list.insert`) because a new integer object is returned.

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given.

The reason for this is that integers, strings, tuples and other types are immutable so *cannot* be modified - instead a new instance must be made. On the other hand lists, sets and other types are mutable so their values can be changed which is why they have methods which don't return the modified list, but instead modify it in place.

Comment: Sorry, immutability not the reason why this syntax does not work, e.g. `set(some_list)` wouldn't change `some_list` even though `list` and `set` objects are mutable.

Comment: @cdarke I agree, however I did not say that in all cases where functions or methods are called on mutable types, the variable is modified in place, merely that in some cases they do *and this is only possible because they are mutable*. I.e. there are no methods of immutable types or functions that can be called on immutable types that modify that immutable type in place - this is the vary meaning of immutable (unchangeable). Sorry if my wording was off and it came across the other way around.